# Find the fifth expression of Taylor's for $\sin (\tan x)$ around $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the fifth expression of Taylor's for $\sin (\tan x)$ around $x=0$

**My try:**
$$\sin x=x+r_{1}(x), r_{1}(x)=o(x)$$ $$\tan x=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^5+r_{2}(x), r_{2}(x)=o(x^5)$$ So: $$\sin \tan x=(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^5)+r_{3}(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^5+r_{2}(x)))=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^5+r_{4}(x), r_{4}(x)=o(x)$$
That is why fifth expression of Taylor's is $\frac{2}{15}x^5$ for me. 
However Mathematica say that: $$\sin \tan x=x+\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{40}+o(x^5)$$ Where have I a mistake?

Comment: Why are you dropping the third and fifth power terms in your expansion of sin(x)?

Comment: @Mjiig Because I decided that I did not need it in this task

Comment: That was your mistake! The third and fifth powers of $(x+\frac {x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^3)$ contribute to the third and fifth powers of $x$ in $\sin\tan x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the same symbol $x$  for two different variables :

$$\sin(\tan(x))=\sin(X)\quad\text{with}\quad X=\tan(x).$$
$$\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^6)$$
$$\sin(X)=X-\frac{X^3}{6}+\frac{X^5}{120}+O(X^6)$$

$\sin(\tan(x))=\big(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^6)\big) -\frac{\big(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+O(x^4)\big)^3 }{6}+\frac{\big(x+O(x^2)\big)^5}{120}+O(x^6)$

Expand each term and eliminate the powers of $x$ higher than 5 :

$\big(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+O(x^4)\big)^3=x^3+x^5+O(x^6)$

$\big(x+O(x^2)\big)^5=x^5+O(x^6)$

Put them into the above equation for $\sin(\tan(x))$ and simplify :

$\sin(\tan(x))=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15} -\frac{x^3+x^5 }{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O(x^6)$

$$\sin(\tan(x))=x+\frac{x^3}{6} -\frac{x^5}{40}+O(x^6)$$

NOTE :

Your calculus is not correct at $ $$\sin \tan x=(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^5)+r_{3}(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^5+r_{2}(x)))$ because one must take the term $(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^5)$ at power 3 and the next at power 5.

Write explicitly $r_1(x),r_2(x), r_3(x)$ as series of powers of $x$ and you will understand.

Comment: Why can you use other Taylor's expansions in the same function: $\sin(\tan(x))=\big(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^6)\big) -\frac{\big(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+O(x^4)\big)^3 }{6}+\frac{\big(x+O(x^2)\big)^5}{120}+O(x^6)$? I thought that I must use the same expansion in all function

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand what you mean. In my answer the usual series expansions are used for the functions sin and tan. The key point is to not confuse the respective variables. In $\sin(x)$ and in $\sin(\tan(x))$ the $x$ are different. Thus, first one have to write the Taylor series of $\tan(x)$. Second one have to write the Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ but since it is not the same $x$, better use a different symbol : $\sin(X)$ . Third, substitute X by $\tan(x)$, that is put the second series into the first one. That way you use the same expansion method all along the calculus.

Comment: I meant that I thought if I choose one expansion then I must use it in all function. So I can write for example $\sin(\tan(x))=\big(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^6)\big) -\frac{\big(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^6)\big)^3 }{6}+\frac{\big(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^6)\big)^5}{120}+O(x^6)$ but I can't write $\sin(\tan(x))=\big(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^6)\big) -\frac{\big(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+O(x^4)\big)^3 }{6}+\frac{\big(x+O(x^2)\big)^5}{120}+O(x^6)$ because these are other expansion in $X, X^3, X^5$

Comment: OK. But the expansions of $X,X^3,X^5$ are very simple : $X^3=x^3+x^5+O(x^6)$ and $X^5=x^5+O(x^6)$.  With $r_1(x), r_2(x),r_2(x),...$ you cannot avoid also to expand them, which will be at least as complicated and probably more.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Try starting $$\sin (\tan x)=\tan x - \frac{(\tan x)^3}{3!} + \frac{(\tan x)^5}{5!} +o((\tan x)^5)$$

And you must consider all terms that have $x^5$ in them, for example, $(\tan x)^3= (x+\frac{x^3}{3} +\frac{2}{15}x^5)^3$ have $(\frac{x^5}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{3})$

So, if you gather all the $x^5$ terms respectively, you'll find out that the coefficient of $x^5$ in the series is $$\frac{2}{15} -\frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3})+\frac{1}{5!}= \frac{-3}{120}=\frac{-1}{40}$$

Comment: Ok, but why my answer is bad when I write $\sin (\tan x)=\tan x+ r(\tan x)$?

Comment: Because you aren't taking all the $x^5$ terms this way. As I wrote in my answer, the $3^{rd}$ expression of $\sin x$ (that you didn't consider in your answer) has in it a hidden $x^5$ term

Answer (score 1):

Taylor's expansions up to the same order can be composed. So you have to consider the Taylor polynomial of degree $5$ for $\sin x$, and substitute $x$  with the degree $5$ Taylor polynomial for $\tan x$, truncating the successive powers of the latter polynomial at degree $5$.

As a start-up, here is the computation for degree $3$:
$$\bigl(x+\tfrac13x^3 +\tfrac2{15}x^5\bigr)^2=x^2+\tfrac19x^4+o(x^5),$$
\begin{align}
&\text{so that}\hspace{6em} &\bigl(x+\tfrac13x^3 +\tfrac2{15}x^5\bigr)^3&=\bigl(x^2+\tfrac19x^4+o(x^5)\bigr)\bigl(x+\tfrac13x^3 +\tfrac2{15}x^5\bigr)&\hspace{6em} \\
&&&=x^3+\tfrac13x^5+\frac19x^5+o(x^5)=\color{red}{x^3+\tfrac49x^5}+o(x^5).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The organized and detailed solution must be:
$$\sin y=y-\frac{y^3}{6}+\frac{y^5}{120}+O(y^7);\\
\sin \overbrace{\tan x}^{y}=\overbrace{\tan x}^{y}-\frac{(\overbrace{\tan x}^{y})^3}{6}+\frac{(\overbrace{\tan x}^{y})^5}{120}+O((\overbrace{\tan x}^{y})^7)=\\
\tan x=\color{blue}{x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^7)};\\
(\tan x)^2=(\tan x)(\tan x)=\left[x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^7)\right]\left[x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^7)\right]=\\
x^2+\frac23x^4+O(x^6);\\
(\tan x)^3=(\tan x)^2(\tan x)=\left[x^2+\frac23x^4+O(x^6)\right]\left[x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^7)\right]=\\
\color{red}{x^3+x^5+O(x^7)};\\
(\tan x)^5=(\tan x)^3(\tan x)^2=\left[x^3+x^5+O(x^7)\right]\left[x^2+\frac23x^4+O(x^6)\right]=\\
\color{green}{x^5+O(x^7)};\\
\sin \tan x=\color{blue}{\left[x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+O(x^7)\right]}-\frac{\color{red}{x^3+x^5+O(x^7)}}{6}+\frac{\color{green}{x^5+O(x^7)}}{120}+O(x^7)=\\
x+\left(\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{2x^5}{15}-\frac{x^5}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}\right)+O(x^7)=\\
x+\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{40}+O(x^7).$$